# After forced quit, "killall Finder" says "No matching processes..." but PID still exists?

Tags: kill, pid, finder, relaunch

Here's one for ya. Upon a forced quit of the Finder with unsuccessful relaunch, "killall Finder" in terminal returns:

```
"No matching processes belonging to you were found"
```

Oddly enough, the PID for finder does actually show up after a "ps -A" to reveal all processes. But the time is perpetually listed as 0:00:00, upon repeated PID listings.

I tried the following to manually launch it:

```
open /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app
```

But it puked:

```
LSOpenFromURLSpec() failed with error -600 for the file /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app.
```

Any other ideas on a Finder relaunch that don't involve rebooting? (I usually have 6 spaces open at once, each with a handful of apps and it's a pain reloading them all.)

Comment: This belongs on superuser.com

Comment: Thanks, sc. Haven't used it yet, but just checked it out.

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar problem after trying to relaunch Xcode. I got the same `failed with error -600`.

The problem dissappeared after I inserted sleep in 300 mseconds (sleep 0.3).
I created a bash script which did the following:

```
# softly kill Xcode
killall -SIGINT Xcode
sleep 0.3 

# open Xcode
open /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app
```